# Raising differential to a power n in an integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I was reading a paper and encountered an integral where the differential, $dx$, was raised to the power $4$. What does this mean? Is this some kind of special integral?

$$\int d^4x$$

Comment: Can you provide a link to the article? My guess is that the `x` is a $4$-vector, so $\mathrm{d}^4 \mathbf{x}$ is the $4$-volume element generated by incrementing each component of $\mathbf{x}$ by an infinitesimal amount.

Comment: This is most likely referring to the notation $\int d^4x = \iiiint dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4$. Without more details from the paper, this is my best guess.

Comment: Link to the article is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.1855v1.pdf